# Mac slow because of ssd

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hard-drive, ssd

I bought used macbook pro 2012. The hdd was already changed to 120GB SSD (SPCC Solid State Disk, S9FM01.8). It was working fine on Yosemite until I wiped the disk and did an internet recovery. Recovery went well but extremely slow. After installation the mac is working but it takes about 2 minutes between mouse clicks. I did enable trim using using "trim enabler". I also made sure it is and SSD problem by putting back HDD. It works fine with an HDD.

The SSD also works fine, because when I instelled ubuntu on it it has no problem with it and SSD test showed about 500MB read and 300MB write speeds.
What could be the problem or what are some other ways to debug it. There is nothing on the internet that was of any help.

Comment: It might be an idea to make a clearly readable and to the point question, i.e. What is causing my Mac to do.... ?

Comment: @unknowndomain What was wrong with his question? The question is clear and it's only two paragraphs long.